# Deactivate Nvidia Graphic-Card CLI

Tags: command-line, fedora, nvidia, video, hybrid-graphics

How can I deactivate my dedicated NVIDIA gc via CLI?

My Laptop has 2 graphic cards, an integrated INTEL gc and a dedicated NVIDIA gc?
I have no use for the NVIDIA gc, because I don't play anymore (sadly).
I haven't installed any driver for the gc.
Due to power save reasons I want to deactivate the dedicated one in a systemd script.

Answer (score 1):

You may deactivate the NVIDIA graphic board in the bios. There should be options like Discrete/Hybrid/Integrated, Discrete means NVidia, Integrated means Intel, and Hybrid means chose dynamically (use the Integrated option).

If you want to keep the possibility of using the NVIDIA graphic board, keep "Hybrid" in the bios, and install / configure Bumblebee [1].

[1] http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html

Comment: I have no option to deactivate my card in bios.

Answer (score 1):

If the reason is energy saving then the only efficient way is : **To unplug your Nvidia gc!**

Preventing whatever (proprietary / opensource) dedicated driver to load (as suggested elsewhere) won't save watts!
The result would rather be the opposite : You'll loose any chance of driving energy saving modes (if any)

If running Nvidia proprietary drivers, depending on the model, there are a couple of configuration settings dedicated to power management modes. Find them and use them.
If running *Nouveau*... argh! Sorry... I know nothing about it. But the kernel documentation is there to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can blacklist the modules for your nvidia-card.

```
echo "blacklist nouveau" | tee  >  /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-card.conf
```

and

```
echo "blacklist nvidia | tee -a > /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-card.conf
```

Or maybe you can disable the card in Bios/Uefi.

And what ist a sysd script?